# In Which Android Version The SlideMenu Can be Applicable in - Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-sliding

Hi friends i have one small clarification in which basic version the sliding menu can be applicable? Please help me friends. thank you.

Comment: `which basic version`... ??? do you mean `which JAVA version`?!

Comment: Do you mean `SDK Version`?

Comment: Android Version And SDK Version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/. This Sliding menu is supported from Android API 11 version only.

If you want to implement for lower end of device, you can check out https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Common-Navigation-Paradigms

Comment: sliding menu also worked well in api level 8.. you need support library 7.

Comment: support library 7 means what?

Comment: You Can read more about support library v7 on https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native Navigation Drawer as Sliding Menu. Though The Navigation Drawer supports only API 11 and above. You can use the support Library and use it for Lower versions also. The performance of Navigation Drawer is better. Refer this links for Navigation Drawer

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

And Visit this link for support Library

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: if i installed a support library, then i can use my apk for lower version android phone? @Saras

Comment: Yes you can use the apk for lower versions also. It supports perfectly